# How to describe mounttables in core-site xml for federation?

Tags: hadoop

Where can i find mountTable.xml and how to add namespaces inside mountTable.xml?

What does the below given statement mean?

```
<configuration xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"> <xi:include href="mountTable.xml" /></configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mountTable.xml` does not exist by default. Create one under `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR` and add all the mounttable configuration properties in it. 
For example,

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.viewfs.mounttable.ClusterX.homedir</name>
    <value>/home</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.viewfs.mounttable.ClusterX.link./home</name>
    <value>hdfs://nn1-clusterx.example.com:8020/home</value>
  </property>
  ....
</configuration>
```

Since the mounttable properties are defined in a different file than `core-site.xml`, add this configuration element in `core-site.xml` to include all the properties defined in `mountTable.xml`.

```
<configuration xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"> 
  <xi:include href="mountTable.xml" />
</configuration>
```

It is not mandatory that the mounttable properties has to be in a different file, you can directly include them in `core-site.xml`.

Refer [A Mount Table Configuration Example](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/ViewFs.html#Appendix:_A_Mount_Table_Configuration_Example)